# How to do a paired t test with gtsummary for several levels of a third categorical variable

Tags: r, gtsummary

I am trying to use the package `gtsummary` to do a paired t-test. I want to do it for each of the two values of the variable `desg`.

I tried to adapt one of the examples in the docs of the package, but I couldn't obtain a clear result since the example only uses one dependent variable and a treatment (group).

What am I doing wrong?

```
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(gtsummary)

df <- tibble(ID = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 
                     6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12,
                     13, 13, 14, 14, 15, 15, 16, 16, 17, 17, 18, 18, 19, 19,
                     20, 20, 21, 21, 22, 22, 23, 23, 24, 24),
              desg = c(rep(c("x01", "x02"), 24)), 
              group = c(rep(c("I", "I", "F", "F"), 12)),
              values = c(8, 9, 10,  9, 10,  9,  3, 10,  9,  8,  8,  8, 10,  9, 10,
                         7,  9,  6, 10,  8, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10,  8, 10, 10, 10,
                         10, 8, 9, 10, 9, 10, 9, 7, 8, 9, 6, 7, 8, 6, 6, 5, 7,
                         9, 8)
)

df$desg <- as.factor(df$desg)
df$I_F <- as.factor(df$group)

df <- df %>% arrange(group, desg)

df_paired <- 
  df %>%
  select(group, desg, values) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup()

# you must first delete incomplete pairs from the data, then you can build the table
df_paired %>%
  # delete missing values
  filter(complete.cases(.)) %>%
  # keep IDs with both measurements
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(n() == 2) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  # summarize data
  tbl_summary(by = group, include = -id) %>%
  add_p(
    test = list(
      values ~ "paired.t.test"
    ),
    group = id
  )
#> boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')
#> boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')
Characteristic  F, N = 241  I, N = 241  p-value2
desg            >0.9
    x01 12 (50%)    12 (50%)    
    x02 12 (50%)    12 (50%)    
values          0.8
    3   1 (4.2%)    0 (0%)  
    5   0 (0%)  1 (4.2%)    
    6   3 (13%) 1 (4.2%)    
    7   1 (4.2%)    3 (13%) 
    8   5 (21%) 5 (21%) 
    9   5 (21%) 6 (25%) 
    10  9 (38%) 8 (33%) 
1 n (%)
2 random intercept logistic regression; Paired t-test
Created on 2023-10-07 with reprex v2.0.2
```

Comment: Statistically you should instead be using multiple regression.

Answer (score -1):

```
lm(values ~ desg+group, data=df)
```

Has the advantage of a partitioning the analysis by group but also taking into account the overall relationship of values with the other independent variable.

Comment: The fact that data is paired has no importance when doing a regression?

Comment: It is crucial that the data are paired. If you only had one continuous predictor it would be equivalent to a paired t-test.